# Fancybox: Add Caption and other things

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'd like to know how I can add more than a title (e.g a caption or a link) to the fancybox.
I am aware that if I add a title="Bla" it'll show up in the box. But if I add something like caption="Blabla" to my image link, what code do I need to have in jquery.fancybox.js to pull that caption tag?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox 2 Custom Titles and Captions \[from A(title) and IMG(alt\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058442/fancybox-2-custom-titles-and-captions-from-atitle-and-imgalt)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need to mess with original *jquery.fancybox.js* file since you could add this option within your own customized fancybox script.

If you are using `HTML5 DOCTYPE`, you could use the `data-*` attribute for you caption so you can have this HTML :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" data-caption="This is the caption" >Open fancybox</a>
```

Then set your custom fancybox script and get the `data-caption` using the `beforeShow` callback like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  beforeShow : function(){
   this.title =  $(this.element).data("caption");
  }
 });
}); // ready
```

That will override the `title` and use the `data-caption` instead.

On the other hand, you may want to keep the `title` attribute and build the fancybox's `title` combining both, `title` and `data-caption` attributes so, for this HTML

```
<a class="fancybox" href="images/01.jpg" title="This is the title" data-caption="This is the caption">Open fancybox</a>
```

Use this script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.fancybox').fancybox({
  beforeShow : function(){
   this.title =  this.title + " - " + $(this.element).data("caption");
  }
 });
}); // ready
```

Additionally, you could also get the `caption/title` from another HTML element within your document (a `<div>` for instance) that can have links or other HTML elements. Check these posts for code examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/8425900/1055987

**NOTE** : this is for fancybox v2.0.6+

Comment: Perfect elegant solution. Thank you!

Comment: @JFK Is there a way to keep/hold the caption visible? In my environmet, the captions disappears after some seconds.

Comment: @TheBndr The captions shouldn't ever disappear http://jsfiddle.net/picssel/1wn1f88b/ ... check you don't have code that actually removes the source of the captions after a time out or so (or reproduce the issue in a fiddle)

Answer (score 10):

Old question, but thanks to JFK's answer I found out that with the latest version of `fancybox` you can add a caption simply by entering a value in the `title=""` attribute (by default). Just make sure it's included on the `<a>` element with the `fancybox` class.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first I've ever read to include it with the link.

Comment: This should now be the accepted answer. Unfortunately OP's been M.I.A. since 2013.