# Is there a way to add HTML code inside the 'alt' attribute using fancybox?

Tags: javascript, html, image, fancybox, alt

I am trying to see if it is possible to add html code inside the 'alt' tag of an image either through the html or using some kind of javascript. I am using fancybox as my image gallery. I'm trying to use fancybox as a form to display an image and on the description of the image, add information with style (like bullet points and breaks) and also add a button that will take you to a different page. Currently I have the button working but that button is in the javascript so every fancybox image has that button and the same url. And i want to have different links to each button on each image.

Here is the javascript that i have that currently displays the alt text under the image in the fancybox.

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({               
                padding : 0,
                beforeShow: function () {
                    this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
                    this.title = '<h4>' + this.title + '</h4>' + '<div style="width:100%; height: 150px; overflow: auto;">' + $(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('alt') + '<a class="button button-small" href="http://www.google.com"> Sign Up </a>' + '</div>';
                },
                helpers : {
                    title : { type: 'inside' },
                }
            });
```

The html in the index.html for that fancybox is:

```
<li class="item-thumbs span3 design">
                                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="The City" href="_include/img/work/full/image-01-full.jpg">
                                    <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                                    <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                                </a>
                                <!-- Thumb Image and Description -->
                                <img src="_include/img/work/thumbs/image-01.jpg" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus quis elementum odio. Curabitur pellentesque, dolor vel pharetra mollis.">
                            </li>
```

Comment: If you want a more complex fancybox `title` (with html, hyperlinks, etc.), then try using a separated (hidden) html element as in this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/9611664/1055987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `alt` attribute (not tag) is by definition plain text, so whatever you insert there will be taken as plain text (not markup) by browsers. If you mess around with code that inserts strings that look like HTML tags into an `alt` attribute value and then parse and process them as markup, this is no different with similar play with other attributes.

The `alt` attribute has a well-defined job, to act as a textual replacement for the image when the image is not displayed but e.g. spoken, rendered with a Braille device, or displayed as text. It is thus unproductive to try to use it for other purposes.

Similar considerations apply to the `title` attribute.

To use data that will be parsed as HTML, it is thus much better to use a custom attribute, specifically a [`data-*` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes), like `data-desc`, or whatever you prefer. They have no default processing in browsers or search engines, so they are safe to use for private purposes.

Comment: @marcopolo : if you want to use (html5) `data-*` attributes, here there are some examples http://stackoverflow.com/a/12357445/1055987 however they may not be suitable for including html tags so see my comment on your question for a better option.

Comment: @Jukka: So i did a little research on using data-* attributes and tried it on my website and it worked! Now i can add any html attribute with in the new "data-description" attribute and it displaces it perfectly. In the Javascript file i replaced the: ...$(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('alt') +... with $(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('data-description') +

Comment: @JFK: thank you for those examples. I will save them for future references. Thank you

Comment: @marcopolo : instead of this `$(this.element).parent().find('img').attr('data-description')` you could do this `$(this.element).parent().find('img').data('description')` ...it can be much more pron to failure than extra html elements though (some elements inside the `data-caption` attribute may require to be escaped)