# How to change Fancybox script for having a title and description

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

i have fancybox v. 2.1.5

My script creates a title from `<a title="">` and a description from `<a alt="">`. But as "alt" is not a valid attribute for `<a>`, i would like to call the description or 1) from the `<img alt="">` or a data-fancybox-desc or something like that from the `<a>`.
I do not know anything about javascript and jQuery, can someone change my code for it ?

The HTML which is ok if i want to use `<img alt="">` for description :

```
<div class="view view-add">
    <a href="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/images/41.jpg" class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="group1"  title="Dance in the Dark">
        <img src="http://www.igorlaszlo.com/thumbs/41.jpg" alt="Model : Thierry Mercier" />
        <div class="mask">
            <h4>Dance in the Dark</h4>
            <p>Model : Thierry Mercier</p>
            <div class="info">Click for zoom</div>
         </div>
     </a>
</div>
```

The script what should be changed:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox-thumbs").fancybox({
                padding: 0,

                openEffect : 'elastic',
                openSpeed  : 150,

                closeEffect : 'elastic',
                closeSpeed  : 150,

                closeClick : true,

                prevEffect : 'elastic',
                nextEffect : 'elastic',

                closeBtn  : true,
                arrows    : true,
                nextClick : true,

                beforeShow: function () {

                            this.title = $(this.element).attr('title');
                            this.title = '<h3>' + this.title + '</h3>' + $(this.element).attr('alt') + '<br />';

                afterShow: function() {
                },

                helpers : {
                    title : { type: 'inside' }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9727383/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fancybox 2 Custom Titles and Captions \[from A(title) and IMG(alt\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9058442/fancybox-2-custom-titles-and-captions-from-atitle-and-imgalt)

Comment: Thanks for your help... however i am quiet zero in javascript, i tried a lot of variation, for example (which seems the most logic) : `beforeShow: function () { var title = $(this.element).attr('title'); var alt = $(this.element).find('img').attr('alt'); this.title = '<h3>' + title + '</h3>' + alt + '<br />';` but nothing works. I am sure that i am very close to the right one but i can not put it together. When i made the examples exactly the same way as in the examples from the link you gave me, title remained "undefined" as well.

Comment: see it working and use the code http://jsfiddle.net/Vbmat/2/

Comment: @JFK Thanks a lot, it works now ! First i used the methode `title="<h3>main title</h3><p>second line</p>"` but the corrected script by you is much nicer and works well ! Thanks again !